# Why do minecraft rigs keep crashing?

Tags: rigging, blend-files

I downloaded a Minecraft blender rig from rymdnisse.net, then extracted all the files from the zip folder and wanted to open the character rig.

I started blender, went to file>open, selected the character rig file and clicked "open blender file". And then it crashed.

First of all, I'm new to blender, so I don't know if there's a proper way to open a blend file or something.

I tried dragging and dropping the file into the blender window, appending from library, but most of the times it crashed and when it *did* open, I couldn't do anything with it. That may be because I don't know how to work with armatures yet, but as soon as I clicked "render" it would crash.

Could someone please help me, or explain to me how I'm supposed to handle these files and what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: It should've opened. Are you sure the file extention is .blend?
It also might be corrupted.

Comment: Yes, it is a .blend file.